# MPV (FFmpeg) stack 2 videos and then crop output without re-encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, crop, mpv

I have two 16:9 ratio videos, I want to horizontally stack them, but then crop the resulting video output by about 900px from the right border whilst playing it within mpv and without re-encoding.

[Libavfilter](https://libav.org/documentation/libavfilter.html#crop) does have a crop functionality, but in all [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495301/869881) I've found, the cropping happens before stacking. ([Visual representation of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHn6B.png))

I currently have this which somewhat does what I want:

```
mpv "F:\1.mp4" --external-file="F:\2.mp4" --lavfi-complex="[vid1] scale=1920x1080:flags=spline [vid1_scale]; [vid2] scale=1920x1080:flags=spline [vid2_scale]; [vid1_scale][vid2_scale] hstack [vo]"
```

Is it possible to crop the video output after stacking?

Comment: You say "which somewhat does what I want" but you do not say what it does and what is missing. Have you tried adding cropping to your lavfi parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add crop immediately after hstack:

```
mpv "F:\1.mp4" --external-file="F:\2.mp4" --lavfi-complex="[vid1] scale=1920x1080:flags=spline [vid1_scale]; [vid2] scale=1920x1080:flags=spline [vid2_scale]; [vid1_scale][vid2_scale] hstack,crop=iw-900:ih:0:0 [vo]"
```

Or crop immediately after one of the scales. Doesn't really matter.