# Turn two sets of images into a single comparison video

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, graphics, video-processing

I have two folders with the exact same number of images: "folder1" and "folder2".

I want to take these images, convert them into two videos and have them rendered in the same video file. Think of it like a comparison video that's rendered side-by-side in the same file.

I can use ffmpeg to turn the still images into videos, but this will have one file for each video:

```
ffmpeg -start_number 0 -i "folder1/image-%06d.png" -c:v libx264 -vf "format=yuv420p" video1.mp4

ffmpeg -start_number 0 -i "folder2/image-%06d.png" -c:v libx264 -vf "format=yuv420p" video2.mp4
```

If I want to have both videos rendered side-by-side in the same file I would have to re-encode them, which means quality loss.

Is there a way to do this without the quality loss from reencoding?

Or are there other tools other than ffmpeg that can do this work?

Comment: add `-crf 0` https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#LosslessH.264

Comment: See [Vertically or horizontally stack (mosaic) several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/) using the image sequences as the inputs. Or just use your player to display them side-by-side as in [Multiple side-to-side video streams in one file without transcoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495301/)